# AddID with jQuery on a dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add an id to each div that it generates something like this.

```
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
```

How can I add an id to each of them dynamically?

This is my code

```
var sizestring= $('.wpmlposts').length; 
for (i=0;i <sizestring;i++){
}
```

I know its incomplete, but I have no idea how can I add an id to each div!

Comment: Are you sure you need an `id` for each of those elements?

Comment: Yep, im pretty sure!

Comment: The word is spelled I'm, not im.

Comment: rather adding id after all generated you can add them while creating elements...just a suggestion...:D

Comment: Im using wordpress and they have this weird functions, trust me if i could add it while creating them it would save me alot of time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) or [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) method with a callback function which iterates the elements internally and generates the `id` value using first arguments in the callback which is the index of the element in the collection.

```js
$('.wpmlposts').attr('id', function(i) {
  return 'ranId' + i;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
```

Comment: @V.David : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

To add an `id` is easy, assuming that those elements are present in the DOM already:

```
$('.wpmlposts').prop('id', function(i){
    return 'idPrefix' + i;
});
```

```js
$('.wpmlposts').prop('id', function (i){
  return 'idPrefix' + i;
});
```

```css
div::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
```

Incidentally, you really don't need JavaScript for this, the following would work just as well (in relatively up-to-date browsers):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.wpmlposts')).forEach((el,index) => el.id = 'idPrefix' + i);
```

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.wpmlposts')).forEach((el,index) => el.id = 'idPrefix' + index);
```

```css
div::before {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
```

References:

- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I'm very glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the each function to treat every node individually. [each function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
$('.wpmlposts').each(function(index) {$(this).attr('id', index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var _=$('.wpmlposts'); //let's cache the array
 var length = _.length; //let's cache the  length
    for(var x=0; x<length; x++) {
        _.eq(x).prop('id', x);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like this

```js
$('.wpmlposts').each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('id','randId'+i);
});

// displaying here

$('.wpmlposts').each(function(i){
    console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
<div class="wpmlposts"></div>
```